# change From in when using smtp phpmailer

Tags: php, smtp, sendmail, phpmailer

```
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                                                       
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";     
$mail->Port       = 587;                  
$mail->Username   = "MYUSER";  
$mail->Password   = "MYPASS";    

$mail->Sender = ADDRESS;  // i´ve try this 3 ways.
$mail->SetFrom( ADDRESS , NAME);
$mail->addCustomHeader("From: ADDRESS");


$mail->Subject    = "Contact";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($msg);
$mail->AddAddress('myadress@domain.com');

$mail->Send();
```

I try this three ways to change the From, but had no success. It keep sending it with MYUSER instead of ADDRESS! I don´t know why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: This is a duplicate - gmail does not let you send from non-gmail addresses unless you pre-configure them, or if they handle your domain's email. Whatever you set it to, gmail will override it, which is what you're seeing. Also note that `Sender` and `From` are completely different things.